# ExtJs Sub tabs not activated

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, instantiation

I have two levels of sub tabs in my application. The grid drives the data in my sub tabs.
The tab which is visible(visited) is activated from my grid. The tab which is currently not visited will not display any data unless I visit it again(visit, go to next tab and come back to see data).

[image: sub_tabs]

Is there any way I can instantiate all my tabs, sub tabs along with the grid display?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tabchange event. That should work.

ex:

'tabchange': { fn: function(tab,subtab) {

```
          //your logic goes here.
    }
```

}

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for..